# What's the difference between a Boost Single Pass Iterator and a Forward Traversal Iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iterators

In the [New Iterator Concepts standard proposal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html#iterator-traversal-concepts-lib-iterator-traversal), I am not able to decipher any useful difference between a Single Pass Iterator and a Forward Traversal Iterator.

Does the "Assertion/Note" for the "++r" row in the Forward Traversal table imply that Forward Traversal Iterators are copyable, whereas Single Pass Iterators are not?

Additionally, why does the additional ability to default-construct make an iterator model Forward Traversal? What's the rationale?

Comment: Not sure if duplicate, but it seems close, *very* close: [What's the difference between input iterators and read-only forward iterators?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8869104/500104)

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Xeo. For the sake of clarity, I would appreciate an explicit assertion that your answer to that question applies to the new iterator concepts as well, since the translation from old to new is not strictly one-to-one. Can you confirm that it applies?

Answer (score 5):

The idea of the Single Pass Iterator is that it has *less* requirements than a Forward Traversal iterator. That makes it possible to create one for some cases where multi pass just isn't possible.

Think console input. Even if you could make a copy of the iterator, that wouldn't help you retrieve old keyboard input.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that "multi pass" effectively means "dereferencing more than once without incrementing"?

Comment: No, multi pass means traversing the sequence more than once.