# Own vector assign implementation

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, c++17, assign

I'm implementing stl like vector with writing all default functions. And there is a problem that I don't understand why It calls ragne version of assign for simple types and doesn't default. 
Here is the implementation code:
Vector.h

```
void assign(size_t count, const T& value){ // Default version
                void assign(size_t count, const T& value){
                if(this->_size < count){
                   this->allocator.deallocate(this->arr, this->_capacity);
                   this->arr = this->allocator.allocate(count);

                   this->_capacity = count;
                }
                for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    this->arr[i] = value;

               this->_size = count;
            }

template<class InputIt>
            void assign(InputIt first, InputIt last){ // Range version
                size_t count = std::distance(first,last);
                if(this->_size < count){
                   this->allocator.deallocate(this->arr, this->_capacity);
                   this->arr = this->allocator.allocate(count);

                   this->_capacity = count;
                }
                for(size_t i = 0; first != last; i++)
                    this->arr[i] = *first++;

                this->_size = count;
            }
```

Main code:

```
 Vector<int> vec;
 vec.assign(5,10);
```

Output:

```
/MyVector/MyVector.h: In instantiation of ‘void Vector<T, Allocator>::assign(InputIt, InputIt) [with InputIt = int; T = int; Allocator = std::allocator]’:
../MyVector/main.cpp:52:24:   required from here
../MyVector/MyVector.h:99:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘distance(int&, int&)’
                 size_t count = std::distance(first,last);
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:66:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from ../MyVector/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138:5: note: candidate: template<class _InputIterator> constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator)
     distance(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _InputIterator> constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = int]’:
../MyVector/MyVector.h:99:45:   required from ‘void Vector<T, Allocator>::assign(InputIt, InputIt) [with InputIt = int; T = int; Allocator = std::allocator]’
../MyVector/main.cpp:52:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138:5: error: no type named ‘difference_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<int>’
In file included from ../MyVector/main.cpp:2:0:
../MyVector/MyVector.h: In instantiation of ‘void Vector<T, Allocator>::assign(InputIt, InputIt) [with InputIt = int; T = int; Allocator = std::allocator]’:
../MyVector/main.cpp:52:24:   required from here
../MyVector/MyVector.h:107:36: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
                     this->arr[i] = *first++;
                                    ^~~~~~~~
Makefile:725: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I'm using C++17

Comment: See the cppreference on [`std::vector::assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign). The second overload mentions specifically that certain things are done to avoid selecting this overload when vector contains integral type. The template overload will be selected over your own (if vector type is integral type). You need to provide an implementation that handles it. In C++11, this is done using SFINAE, but I'm not competent enough in templates to answer your question, sorry.

Comment: Why should the "default" version be called? `int` is not `size_t`, so the templated version is a better match. Simply try `void f(size_t, const int&); template <typename T> void f(T, T);` and then call `f(1, 2);`. It will call the templated `f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range version is a better match for `vec.assign(5, 10);` with `InputIt = int`. You should somehow disable that overload for a template parameter that doesn't represent an input iterator.

Let's take a look at [stdlibc++ implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L765):

```
template<typename InputIt, typename = std::RequireInputIter<InputIt>>
void assign(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    M_assign_dispatch(first, last);
}
```

where `RequireInputIter` [is](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h#L248)

```
template<typename InputIt>
using RequireInputIter = typename enable_if<is_convertible<typename
    iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category, input_iterator_tag>::value>::type;
```

In other words, for a deduced type `InputIt`, `iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category` type should be convertible into `input_iterator_tag`. Otherwise, that `assign` overload is silently excluded from the overload resolution set thanks to [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

In C++17, `RequireInputIter` can be simplified with `_t` and `_v` helpers:

```
template<typename InputIt>
using RequireInputIter = enable_if_t<is_convertible_v<typename
    iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category, input_iterator_tag>>;
```

---

Also note that input iterators can be used to traverse a range [only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924799/why-are-inputiterators-one-pass-only). After you call `std::distance(first, last)`, all subsequent attempts to traverse the range are undefined behaviour unless `InputIt` is at least a forward iterator. For input iterators you can't determine how much space to preallocate.

That's why `assign` uses tag dispatch technique internally. With some simplifications it looks like this:

```
template<typename InputIt, typename = std::RequireInputIter<InputIt>>
void assign(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    M_assign_aux(first, last, 
        typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category{});
}
```

There are two `M_assign_aux` overloads

```
template<typename InputIt>
void M_assign_aux(InputIt first, InputIt last, std::input_iterator_tag);

template<typename ForwardIt>
void M_assign_aux(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, std::forward_iterator_tag);
```

to do the assignment. The first one will be used for input iterators only, and the second one - for forward iterators and those derived from it, i.e. bidirectional and random access ones.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @RadicalEdward, updated with tag dispatch for iterator category.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a specific function using cast. Like:
assign( (size_t) 5, (const int&) 10);