# Constraint template function parameter types

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

There are two insert functions, defined as follows

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator>
auto list<T, Allocator>::insert(iterator pos, size_t count, const T & value)->iterator
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        pos = insert(pos, value);
    }
    return pos;
}


template<typename T, typename Allocator>
template<typename InputIt>
 auto list<T, Allocator>::insert(iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last) -> iterator
{
     for (InputIt iter = first; iter != last; ++iter) {
         pos = insert(pos, *iter);// Indirection operator ( * ) is applied to a nonpointer value.
     }
    return pos;
}
```

When the type of T is int,The following call to insert will cause an error

```
list<int> l1;
l1.insert(l1.begin(),10, 2);//cause error
```

Because the second insert function can be matched more accurately than the first (no conversion required)

Is there any way to limit the type of InputIt? This function can only be matched when there is a certain type in InputIt

Comment: What exactly is the problem? https://godbolt.org/z/sh7jsc6ef

Comment: The problem is that l1.insert(l1.begin(),10, 2) calls the second insert function, InputIt is deduced into int, but int cannot be dereferenced

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted? Isn't that evidence that what you're saying happens doesn't actually happen?

Comment: The list is not a list of stl, but a list written by myself

Comment: In that case, can you post a minimal, reproducible example, i.e., a complete program that I can copy and paste with no changes, that will demonstrate the problem when I try it? What you posted is missing the class declaration among other things.

Comment: the code is here:https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/n2xYgGp6T9/

Comment: Or this? [How does a compiler distinguish between two variations of “vector::insert”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45581142/7509065) Or this? [Own vector assign implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61889111/7509065)