# Can I (a) not write through an input iterator, or (b) only read through one once

Tags: c++

Which part of the following statement is incorrect?

> An input iterator can only read from the current position once and must then be incremented. The current position cannot be written to.

Comment: Where did this statement come from, and what do you expect the SO community to do about it?

Comment: Sounds like a homework/exam to me.

Comment: This question comes down to two _easily researchable_ assertions about input iterators. Why did you not simply look up the behaviour of input iterators? _I have answered as a "welcome to SO" present_ but, please, I shall not do that again — you should perform basic research before asking.

Comment: Typical assignment question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find the answer in section 24.2.3 of [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

> An input iterator can only read from the current position once and must then be incremented.

This part is incorrect. You may dereference an input iterator as many times as you like! (*However*, [most input iterators are single-pass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869179/560648).)

> The current position cannot be written to.

This part is correct. You have an *input* iterator.